How do I install pygame on Ubuntu 24?
Pip doesn't work. Python3 base install on Ubuntu wants package installs via apt install python-xyz. And I can't find pygame
_@Sbox:~/Desktop$ python3 -m pip install pygame
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

_@Sbox:...

_@Sbox:~/Desktop$ sudo apt install python-pygame
[sudo] password for kevin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pygame

I'm thinking I just need to add a repo to apt. Looking for what to use and how todo that for pygame. Thanks.

Try apt install python3-pygame or use a Virtual Environment, but don't create an apt repo for pygame unless you're willing to build and upload every version (IIRC).

"apt-cache search pygame" will find the python3-pygame name

apt install python3-pygame
include the 3.
